# Model class representing a calculator

Tags: mvc, objective-c, calculator, finance

I have a simple Model class that represents a calculator.

Header file:

```
@class MMCalculator;

@protocol MMCalculatorDelegate <NSObject>

@required - (void)mmCalculator:(MMCalculator *)mmCalulatorFinishedCalculatingValues;

@end

@interface MMCalculator : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, weak) id <MMCalculatorDelegate> delegate;
@property float calculatedPay;
@property float calculatedSavingsForStuff;
@property float calculatedSavingsForProfitFormula;
@property float calculatedSavingsForTaxes;

- (void)calculateValuesWithMonthlyRevenue:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateYourPay:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateSavingsForStuff:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateSavingsForProfitFormula:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateSavingsForTaxes:(float)monthlyRevenue;

@end
```

Implementation file:

```
#import "MMCalculator.h"

#pragma mark - Static Variables
static float const percentageToPayYourself = 0.50f;
static float const percentageToSaveForStuff = 0.20f;
static float const percentageToSaveForProfitFormula = 0.20f;
static float const percentageToSaveForTaxes = 0.10f;

@implementation MMCalculator

#pragma mark - Calculator Methods
- (void)calculateValuesWithMonthlyRevenue:(float)monthlyRevenue
{
    //Call all 4 calculation methods and set calculated properties
    self.calculatedPay = [self calculateYourPay:monthlyRevenue];
    self.calculatedSavingsForStuff = [self calculateSavingsForStuff:monthlyRevenue];
    self.calculatedSavingsForProfitFormula = [self calculateSavingsForProfitFormula:monthlyRevenue];
    self.calculatedSavingsForTaxes = [self calculateSavingsForTaxes:monthlyRevenue];

    //Call delegate method
    [self.delegate mmCalculator:self];
}
- (float)calculateYourPay:(float)monthlyRevenue
{
    return percentageToPayYourself * monthlyRevenue;
}

- (float)calculateSavingsForStuff:(float)monthlyRevenue
{
    return percentageToSaveForStuff * monthlyRevenue;;
}

- (float)calculateSavingsForProfitFormula:(float)monthlyRevenue
{
    return percentageToSaveForProfitFormula * monthlyRevenue;
}

- (float)calculateSavingsForTaxes:(float)monthlyRevenue
{
    return percentageToSaveForTaxes * monthlyRevenue;
}

@end
```

Here are the key things I am looking for feedback on:

1. Right now I store the class's calculated values in public properties so they can be accessed by other classes. Should it be the class's responsibility to store these calculated values in it's properties, or should it be the responsibility of the class that is calling this class's methods?.
2. Did I define my static variables correctly? Are they following best practices?
3. What do you think of the class's delegate method?
4. Am I following best practices by using floats to represent money? I have a feeling that I should be using something else.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's address your questions:

1. I don't think that storing the calculated values in public properties is a good idea, mainly because If I call `calculateValuesWithMonthlyRevenue` with say, 1000, and then afterwards call `calculateYourPay` with 400, the other properties don't change to reflect my different monthly revenue. Therefore, I'm not sure why these should be stored as properties at all. I would eliminate `calculateValuesWithMonthlyRevenue`, and make this class a singleton with only static methods.
2. In most cases, static constants are written in `ALLCAPS` or `ALL_CAP`, depending on your prefered style. <s>I would define these in your header file (if you want these values to be public) or in your implementation file (if you want the values to be private) with `#define` instead, but that's a matter of personally preference</s>.
3. You don't show us what you do with this delegate method, so I can't exactly be sure what the point of it is. I would omit it for now.
4. Using floats is a bit dangerous as it lends itself to annoying floating-point errors such as .3 turning into .299999999. This is really a question of desired precision. If you're fine with being off by a bit, then floats are pretty decent. If not, you will have to define your own type to represent money.

Comment: In regards to point 2, this isn't the recommended convention for Objective-C and `#define` is heavily recommended against for almost everything in almost every language I'm familiar with.  And in this specific case, it would definitely be recommended to use typed constants as he has done (though, they should be named slightly differently).

Comment: "This is really a question of desired precision." - What would be the best choice if I need pinpoint accuracy since I am dealing with monetary values?

Comment: @user3344977 Integers.  You've marked this answer as accepted, which is fine, but I hope you'll stick around, as I plan on posting quite a few things.

Comment: I would create a object that has dollars and cents (both are integers) for that. Perhaps you can call it `MMMoney`?

Comment: @nhgrif Wait for 10 minutes. I'm posting a new question with some refactoring and things changed. I kind of screwed this one up. I'll link to it in a moment and thanks!

Comment: @mleyfman It should probably only have a single instance variable, but you can call `dollars` on it to return `totalCents / 100` or call `cents` on it to return `totalCents % 100`

Comment: @nhgrif If you want to save a tiny amount of space, sure.

Comment: It's not even about space--does it make sense to have more than 99 cents?

Comment: Well, you could have a class invariant be to have no more than 100 cents at any time. But your solution is probably simpler.

Comment: So you either introduce complicated logic to make sure there's never more than 99 cents, or you just store it as a single instance variable.

Comment: @mleyfman Thank you for the help I appreciate it!

Answer (score 3):

The use of a `delegate` here is absolutely overkill.

Delegates are useful for plenty of things.

- When you're performing asynchronous code, using a delegate let's you call back and let the delegate know when the asynchronous code is complete.
- When you're performing synchronous code but the delegate wants to know about specific events in the code or the delegated object needs to ask the delegate for specific information in a specific order (think about how `UITableView`'s work)
- When you're performing synchronous code but the delegated object waits for user input, processes it, then informs the delegate that it's done with that.

There are probably other cases, but this covers most typical use cases.  Your code doesn't fall into any of these categories.

Your code doesn't fall into any of these categories.  And what's worse, we're not actually returning anything useful to the delegate.

In almost every use case, a delegate already has a reference to the object it's delegating.  It's not impossible for this to be not be the case, but it's rare.  And our code executes synchronously.  Any code that you want to put in the delegate's call back method could simply be put in the line right after we call `calculateValuesWithMonthlyRevenue:`--in the scope in which we already have a reference to the object the delegate method returns.

With that said, it is good for delegate methods to pass a reference to the delegated object when called (`self`).  Nothing prevents Object A from delegating multiple objects that will all call that delegate method.  Passing a reference to `self` is the best way to let the delegate distinguish which object is calling the method.

But here, the delegate pattern is just complete overkill.  We're calling very uncomplicated synchronous code that doesn't have various important events that the delegate might want to know about and doesn't ever need to wait for user input.

Comment: Thank you for adding this as well. I was trying way to hard to use a delegate. I have an app with asynchronous code and I'm definitely going to add a delegate to manage that. Your answers always make me learn a lot and you put everything in such an easy to understand way. Thank you!

Comment: PS. I implemented your changes here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/60532/further-refactored-model-class-that-represents-a-calculator

Answer (score 2):

The preferred naming style for constants in Objective-C is to prefix the constant with the letter `k`, and generally after this, follow regular `kCamelCasing` rules.

For example:

```
#pragma mark - Const Variables
static CGFloat const kPercentageToPayYourself = 0.50f;
static CGFloat const kPercentageToSaveForStuff = 0.20f;
static CGFloat const kPercentageToSaveForProfitFormula = 0.20f;
static CGFloat const kPercentageToSaveForTaxes = 0.10f;
```

Notice I renamed the `#pragma mark` to `Const Variables`, as I feel this is the more important aspect of these variables.

I've also changed the type to `CGFloat`.  There's not a particularly good reason to use `float` in Objective-C.  A `CGFloat` is a `float` on 32-bit systems and a `double` on 64-bit systems.  Meanwhile, a `float` is always a `float` and a `double` is always a `double`.

---

```
- (float)calculateYourPay:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateSavingsForStuff:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateSavingsForProfitFormula:(float)monthlyRevenue;
- (float)calculateSavingsForTaxes:(float)monthlyRevenue;
```

There's no particularly good reason for these to be instance methods.  They don't rely on the state of the instance at all.  These should either be class methods or C-Style functions.

If you move them to class methods, the naming is okay.  If you change them to C-style functions (which I think I'd prefer to see), we need to fix the naming to something we can be certain won't have any naming collisions.

Comment: +1 for the float advice. I had no idea that CGFloat would dynamically switch like that to accommodate the different systems.